# Python Subprocess stdin

Tags: python

I am using 2 python scripts:
Script 1 uses subprocess.Popen() to execute a process in Script 2. While this process is executed (it takes some time), Script 1 is doing other stuff.
Question 1) Is subprocess.Popen the best way to solve this issue?
Question 2) Is there any way to pass variables (only int/float values) from Script 1 to Script 2 BESIDES using communicate()? How do I make use of these variables in Script 2 (i.e. how do I address them)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

if both are python why bother going to the terminal?

You could just use pythons threading. If you'd do it through terminal you can pass the arguments like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py", "args"])
process.communicate()
```

or at least something along those lines (this probably is wrong I'v never called a python with Popen). How I'd do it is by using the python Threading module (So This will not work with Popen described in the above, if you want a specific answer using that I'd like to see a bit how those script files look like). Anyway:

script1.py:

```
from threading import Thread
from sources.script2 import prnt
import  time

# 'Script1 function'
def prnt1():
    for i in range(5000):
        print('script1: %s' % i)    
        time.sleep(0.5)

# Starting 'script2'
t = Thread(target=prnt, args=(100, 4500)).start()
prnt1()
```

script2.py:

```
import time

def prnt(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        print('script2: %s' % i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

But like said above if we don't know anything about the scripts you want to run it's hard to give advice. does your script have a function defined in it as entry point? or only as standalone?,ect...